# How to replace text in multiple divs according conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to replace the text of many divs, where according to the text of each div, put a text or another.

Example: If the text is 0, replace it with "no quota" and if it is different from 0, put "Yes it has".

Html code:

```
 <div><p id="text">1</p></div>
 <div><p id="text">0</p></div>
 <div><p id="text">1</p></div>
```

JS code:

```
    $('#text').text(function(){
        if($(this).text() == '0')
        {
            $(this).text('No quota');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).text('"Yes it has');
        }
    });
```

But only changes the first element and the others left with the same text.
As I can change the text for each item? Greetings from Chile.

Answer (score 3):

you have multiple instances of the same id. each id needs to be unique - which is why its only affecting the first item. Change the id to a class and you will be able to change each p to the new text. Also spotted a typo in the last else text (correctedin the code below).

```
 <div><p class="text">1</p></div>
 <div><p class="text">0</p></div>
 <div><p class="text">1</p></div>

$('.text').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == '0')
    {
        $(this).text('No quota');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text('Yes it has');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, with your help I managed to fix this little problem haha. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: Why did you change from one call to `.text()` to using `.each()`?

Comment: @Barmar - I changed it because the original call was $('#text').text(.. which was part of the problem - since the issue at hand was the id of "text" was present in each of the <p>'s. Therefore when I changed the <p>'s to have the class of "text" - I also changed the call to iterate through each of the <p>'s with that class and to use $(this) correctly. Perhaps it could have been left, but I prefer to be able to see what scope $(this) is referring to.

Comment: You're right, he's not using the function argument to `.text()` correctly. I've written an answer that shows how to do it properly.

Answer (score 3):

ID is to be used as unique identification number hence only first item changed. Change ID to CLASS should solve the issue.

Comment: ha ha @Ethan Doh - already posted that - just got in ahead of you :))

Comment: Missed by a minute. LOL

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved. Greetings from Chile.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

First, as others have noted, you should be using a class instead of ID if you want to match multiple elements.

Second, when you give a function argument to `.text()`, it receives the old text as an argument, and should return the new text rather than calling `.html()` within it. So it should be:

```js
$('.text').text(function(i, oldtext) {
  return oldtext == '0' ? 'No quota' : 'Yes it has';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p class="text">1</p></div>
<div><p class="text">0</p></div>
<div><p class="text">1</p></div>
```